# Java: Detecting duplicates in Array

Tags: java

I have to write a program that, giving in input various chess pieces, adds them in an array and then finds possible duplicates...

Comment: What debugging have you done?

Comment: Let me take a wild guess: `Piece` does not override the `.equals` method. Does it?

Comment: This condition `chessboard[k] == (chessboard[i]) && chessboard[k] == null` is only `true` when both `chessboard[k]` and `chessboard[i]` are `null`. Also, keep in mind that `==` compares if two variables refer to the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem:

When you are adding the first chess piece, `i` is 0, right? And in the inner for loop, `k` also starts off as 1, right? So obviously, `chessboard[k]` and `chessboard[i]` are equal because `k` and `i` are equal!

To solve this, simply include a `i != k` condition:

```
  for (int k=0; k<chessboard.length ; k++){
         // note the condition here
         if (k != i && chessboard[k] == (chessboard[i]) && chessboard[k] == null){
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error! There is a duplicate piece on the chessboard: "+chessboard[k]);
                 System.exit(0);
             }
          }
  break;
  }
```

Second problem:

`==` compares whether the two operands are the *same* object. Even if two chess piece objects have the same color, type and position, they can still be two independent objects. What you really need here is a way to compare the chess piece objects logically (when two chess pieces' positions are equal, they are equal).

To do this, just add an `equals` method to `Piece`. This is a simple implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instance of Piece) {
        Piece other = (Piece)obj;
        return other.position.equals(this.position);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can then call this method, instead of using `==`.

Third problem:

This is not really a problem, but I suggest you to change the type of the array to `Piece[]` instead of `Object[]`, unless you want to store stuff other than chess pieces in there.

Comment: First of all, thank you! I've changed everything you said, but the compiler gives me this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at main.main(Main.java:22).`
Line 22 is this: `if (k != i && chessboard[k].equals(chessboard[i]) && chessboard[k] == null){`

Comment: @Mark Arrange the conditions like this: `k != i && chessboard[k] == null && chessboard[k].equals(chessboard[i])`

Comment: @Mark that exception says that something is null. Try printing every variable on that line and see which is null. This is really basic debugging. also I realised that you should probably move the duplicate checking code outside the `if (answer == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)` block